# Function of Smooth Muscles in the skin

Tags: human-biology, muscles, skin

I understand that the overall function is voluntary movement, but is it the same in the skin? Is the main function in the skin movement or is there a greater function? Could anyone could provide this information or at least recommend a site that could help me with this research, as I have been searching and I haven't been able to find the answer?

Answer (score 3):

Smooth muscle in the skin actually produces very little motion.  They are found in special places, such as the areolas of the nipple, the tunica dartos of the scrotum, and also around hair follicles.

Smooth muscles that surround hair follicles give you what is known as goosebumps - they contract all together, creating a bump in your skin around the hair follicle.  This can happen when you're cold, scared, or experiencing strong emotion.

---

Sources:

- [Skin Tissue Engineering and Regenerative Medicine, Justine Fenner, Richard A.F. Clark, 2016; Chapter 1](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/B9780128016541000012)